# Get max value per key in a javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Say, I have the following array:

```
[ 
  {a:1, b:"apples"}, 
  {a:3, b:"apples"}, 
  {a:4, b:"apples"}, 
  {a:1, b:"bananas"}, 
  {a:3, b:"bananas"}, 
  {a:5, b:"bananas"}, 
  {a:6, b:"bananas"}, 
  {a:3, b:"oranges"}, 
  {a:5, b:"oranges"}, 
  {a:6, b:"oranges"}, 
  {a:10, b:"oranges"} 
]
```

I want to efficiëntly get for each type of 'b' the whole object with the highest a, so my function should produce:

```
[
  {a:4, b:"apples"},
  {a:6, b:"bananas"},
  {a:10, b:"oranges"}
]
```

Now I would do something like this:

```
var cache = {};
var resultobj = {};
result = [];
array.forEach(function (r) {
 if (cache[r.b] && cache[r.b] > r.a) {
   result[r.b] = r;
 }
})
for (var key in result) {
 result.push(result[key]);
}
```

That looks terrible inefficiënt...?

Comment: That's an efficient way to do it. You only make one pass through the array and then one more pass over the results.

Comment: looks pretty good - O(n) is OK speed for such issue )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a two-liner in ES5 and an one-liner is ES6:

```js
ary = [ 
  {a: 0, b:"apples"}, 
  {a:-3, b:"apples"}, 
  {a:-4, b:"apples"}, 
  {a:1, b:"bananas"}, 
  {a:3, b:"bananas"}, 
  {a:5, b:"bananas"}, 
  {a:6, b:"bananas"}, 
  {a:3, b:"oranges"}, 
  {a:5, b:"oranges"}, 
  {a:6, b:"oranges"}, 
  {a:10, b:"oranges"} 
]

// ES5

maxes = {};
ary.forEach(function(e) {
  maxes[e.b] = e.b in maxes ? Math.max(maxes[e.b], e.a) : e.a;
});

document.write('<pre>'+JSON.stringify(maxes,0,3));
            
// ES6
 
maxes = ary.reduce((m, e) => 
  Object.assign(m, { [e.b]: e.b in m ? Math.max(m[e.b], e.a) : e.a }), {});

document.write('<pre>'+JSON.stringify(maxes,0,3));
```

Comment: You should include in your answer how and why it works.

Comment: @Ginden: "how" would be no problem, but "why" is really puzzling me ;)

Comment: This does what I need, and I can quite follow it. Smart in the Math argument: maxes[e.b] || e.a

I think I go further with this one!

Comment: ah. Nice. Well actually [a] is a timestamp in my case, so always positive.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

#### Logic:

- loop over array
- check if value exist in the last element. (*Assumption: Data is sorted based on `b`*).
- replace if match found, else push it.

```js
var data = [ 
  {a:1, b:"apples"}, 
  {a:3, b:"apples"}, 
  {a:4, b:"apples"}, 
  {a:1, b:"bananas"}, 
  {a:3, b:"bananas"}, 
  {a:5, b:"bananas"}, 
  {a:6, b:"bananas"}, 
  {a:3, b:"oranges"}, 
  {a:5, b:"oranges"}, 
  {a:6, b:"oranges"}, 
  {a:10, b:"oranges"} 
]

var distinctB = data.slice(0,1);
data.forEach(function(o){
  if(distinctB[distinctB.length-1] && o.b !== distinctB[distinctB.length-1].b){
    distinctB.push(o);
  }
  else{
    distinctB[distinctB.length-1] = o;
  }
});

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(distinctB,0,4) + "</pre>");
```

Answer (score 1):

It works with a little help from an object for the indices.

```js
var data = [{ a: 1, b: "apples" }, { a: 3, b: "apples" }, { a: 4, b: "apples" }, { a: 1, b: "bananas" }, { a: 3, b: "bananas" }, { a: 5, b: "bananas" }, { a: 6, b: "bananas" }, { a: 3, b: "oranges" }, { a: 5, b: "oranges" }, { a: 6, b: "oranges" }, { a: 10, b: "oranges" }],
    result = function (array) {
        var r = [], o = {};
        array.forEach(function (a) {
            if (!(a.b in o)) {
                o[a.b] = r.push(a) - 1;
                return;
            }
            if (r[o[a.b]].a < a.a) {
                r[o[a.b]] = a;
            }
        });
        return r;
    }(data);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Nice also, how many comments here... :) For me this one is harder to read.

Comment: but it's pretty straight forward. and it works for unsorted data.

Answer (score 1):

You are close, you have some little wrong logic in the code, you have declared the `cache`, but don't have used it.

```
if (cache[r.b] && cache[r.b] > r.a) //This always will be "false"
```

See working example

```js
var array = [ { a: 1, b: "apples" }, { a: 3, b: "apples" }, { a: 4, b: "apples" }, { a: 1, b: "bananas" }, { a: 3, b: "bananas" }, { a: 5, b: "bananas" }, { a: 6, b: "bananas" }, { a: 3, b: "oranges" }, { a: 5, b: "oranges" }, { a: 6, b: "oranges" }, { a: 10, b: "oranges" } ];

var cache = {};
array.forEach(function(e) {
    var t = cache[e.b];
    if (t) {
        t.a = t.a > e.a ? t.a : e.a;
    } else {
        cache[e.b] = e;
    }
});

var res = Object.keys(cache).map(e => cache[e]);

document.write(JSON.stringify(res));
```

Answer (score 1):

Really, if your fruit names are going to be unique the best data structure is an object rather than an array of objects.

```
var out = arr.reduce(function (p, c) {
  var key = c.b;
  p[key] = p[key] || 0;
  if (c.a > p[key]) p[key] = c.a;
  return p;
}, {}); // { apples: 4, bananas: 6, oranges: 10 }
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ksjgr1oz/)

Comment: In my case, an array is preferred, because the fruit names cán be unique, but there can be new ones. Also, this data has to be sorted also.
Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Just curious - if an array is preferred why did you choose an answer that returns an object? @Riël

Comment: That is a good catch. actually I just noticed now you mention that. 
I think my last part, doing the for key in ... loop, is going to be there anyway, for both answers.
Your answer is close to my own suggestion, without the ned for caching. Helpful for sure! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Short solution with `Array.foreach` and `Math.max` methods:

```
var map = {},result = [];

obj.forEach(function(v){
   (!(v['b'] in map)) ? map[v['b']] = [v['a']] : map[v['b']].push(v['a']);
});
for (var prop in map) {
    result.push({a: Math.max.apply(null, map[prop]), b: prop});
}

console.log(result);
// the output:
[
  {a:4, b:"apples"},
  {a:6, b:"bananas"},
  {a:10, b:"oranges"}
]
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the values in result `result[r.b] = r;` but comparing the values in `cache` by doing this `if (cache[r.b] && cache[r.b] > r.a) {`

You need to set the values in `cache` rather than `result` and then iterate `cache` for your intended result.

Replace the forEach and for loop with

```
array.forEach(function (r) {
 if (cache[r.b] && cache[r.b] > r.a) {
   cache[r.b] = r.a;
 }
});
for (var key in cache) 
{
 result.push(result[key]);
}
```